# How do I set fixed td cell height in CSS when I already have it set, but it is not being honored?

Tags: html, css, html-table, height, row-height

If you run the example below you will see that the cell height is slightly different in each row.  I need to have it be the same even if the contents is different.

How? I thought I am already setting it by using `height: 1.7em;`, but it seems to be ignored.

```css
#cert_legend {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    
}

#cert_legend th, #cert_legend td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding: 2px;
    overflow: auto; 
    height: 1.7em;
    max-height: 1.7em;
}

#cert_legend tr>th {
    text-align: center;
}
.cert_description {
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table id="cert_legend">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">Test Variable Legend</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cert_title">time</td>
      <td class="cert_description">Minutes elapsed</td>
      <td class="cert_title">DPDsn</td>
      <td class="cert_description">Tested differential pressure vs duty point at design RPM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cert_title">tw</td>
      <td class="cert_description">Water temperature</td>
      <td class="cert_title">Torque</td>
      <td class="cert_description">Pump torque</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cert_title">pfin</td>
      <td class="cert_description">Feed pressure in. This is a relative reading to tank pressure</td>
      <td class="cert_title">Eff</td>
      <td class="cert_description">Pump Efficiency</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a div inside the `td` and set a fixed `height` to it, and set the overflow to be `auto` as you want

```css
td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

td > div {
    height: 1.7em;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam, fugiat delectus explicabo natus tempore, officiis quas in eius dolore cumque non iste eveniet necessitatibus, inventore odio cupiditate consequuntur quis mollitia.
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```